# Enable USB debugging in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to build android apps and I want to know how can I run my app on my phone with usb debugging in flutter ?

Everything is ready but debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
follow the procedure...
1. go to phone "setting"
2. go to "about"
3. tap on "MIUI version" until "Developer" mode not activate
4. then go to "additional /more setting"
5. go to "Developer options"
6. enable "Developer options" and "usb debugging"
then connect your device to your pc ..
```

Happy Coding...